# How do I include an int inside a getline();

Tags: c++, integer, getline

Just a simple question, how do I include `int` values inside  a `getline()`? I have searched online but couldn't find any that helps me. I am reading off a txt file. It is a row of numbers. For eg: `1,2,3,4,5`. I am hoping that I can apply these `int` values anywhere so that the only way I can change the values is through the txt file.
I decided to use `getline()` but realise that I cannot use an integer. I am sorry, I am new to this C++. I hope that you can tell me where I went wrong.
Thanks!

```
This is my struct:
    struct vacancyData {
        int CCSpot;
        int SNSpot;
        int TPSpot;
        int SCSpot;
        int DRSpot;
    };
```

This is my code:

```
 ifstream File2;
    File2.open("Vacancy.txt");
    vector<vacancyData> v1;
    vacancyData f;
    while (getline(File2, f.CCSpot, ','))
    {
        getline(File2, f.SNSpot, ',');
        getline(File2, f.TPSpot, ',');
        getline(File2, f.SCSpot, ',');
        getline(File2, f.DRSpot, '\n');
        v1.push_back(f);
    }
```

Comment: Why not use the formatted input support? `char comma; File2 >> f.SNSpot >> comma ...;`

Comment: If you need a CSV parser, you may want to just use one.

Comment: Yet another alternative, read a string using `getline` and then convert it to an integer using `stoi`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::getline` to do this, but you need use a `std::string` and then to convert it to an integer. One way is to use the [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) function.

Example:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct vacancyData {
    int CCSpot;
    int SNSpot;
    int TPSpot;
    int SCSpot;
    int DRSpot;
};

// Overload operator>> for reading a "vacancyData" struct from an istream (like a file)
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, vacancyData& vd) {
    std::string tmp;
    try {
        if(std::getline(is, tmp, ',')) {
            vd.CCSpot = std::stoi(tmp);
            if(std::getline(is, tmp, ',')) {
                vd.SNSpot = std::stoi(tmp);
                if(std::getline(is, tmp, ',')) {
                    vd.TPSpot = std::stoi(tmp);
                    if(std::getline(is, tmp, ',')) {
                        vd.SNSpot = std::stoi(tmp);
                        if(std::getline(is, tmp, ',')) {
                            vd.SCSpot = std::stoi(tmp);
                            if(std::getline(is, tmp)) {
                                vd.DRSpot = std::stoi(tmp);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(...) { // one of the stoi calls failed
        is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
    }
    
    return is;
}

int main() {
    std::ifstream File2("Vacancy.txt");

    if(File2) {
        // construct the vector using iterators:
        std::vector<vacancyData> v1(std::istream_iterator<vacancyData>(File2), 
                                    std::istream_iterator<vacancyData>{});
        
        // use the filled vector "v1" ...
    }
}
```

But since there is built-in support for extracting `int`s directly from `istream`s, I suggest using that instead.

Example:

```cpp
// A small support class to "eat" separators, like comma and newline
struct eater { char ch; };

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, eater& e) {
    if(is.peek() == e.ch) is.ignore();    // if the next char is the expected, skip it
    else is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);  // else set the failbit
    return is;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, vacancyData& vd) {
    eater comma{','};
    eater newline{'\n'};

    return is >>
        vd.CCSpot >> comma >>
        vd.SNSpot >> comma >>
        vd.TPSpot >> comma >>
        vd.SCSpot >> comma >>
        vd.DRSpot >> newline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer to the question

> How do I include an int inside a getline()

is: This is not possible at all.

`std::getline` is basically used to read a `std::string` from a stream, until a delimiter is found. In most cases, and that is also a default argument, the delimiter is '\n'. And with that, a complete line is read into a `std::string`. Please read [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) for a description.

If your input data is OK in most cases, then no `std::getline` is needed. Basic input validation can also be done directly. Please see the below example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct VacancyData {
    int CCSpot;
    int SNSpot;
    int TPSpot;
    int SCSpot;
    int DRSpot;
};

int main() {
    // Filename
    const std::string fileName{ "r:\\vacancy.txt" };

    // Open file and check, if it could be opened. Use C++17 if-statement with initializer
    if (std::ifstream vacancyFileStream{ fileName }; vacancyFileStream) {
        
        // Here we will stor our data
        std::vector<VacancyData> all{};

        // Temps, to check, if delimiter is comma
        char c1{}, c2{}, c3{}, c4{};

        // This is one for loop and will read the complet file and do basic input validation
        for (VacancyData vc{};
            (vacancyFileStream >> vc.CCSpot >> c1 >> vc.SNSpot >> c2 >> vc.TPSpot >> c3 >> vc.SCSpot >> c4 >> vc.DRSpot) &&
            c1 == ',' && c2 == ',' && c3 == ',' && c4 == ',';
            all.push_back(vc))

            ; // Empt loop body. No statement within for loop body

        // Ws there an error and could all data be read?
        if (vacancyFileStream.fail() || not vacancyFileStream.eof())
            std::cerr << "\n\nErorw hile reading input data\n\n";

        for (const VacancyData& vc : all)
            std::cout << vc.CCSpot << '\t' << vc.SNSpot << '\t' << vc.TPSpot << '\t' << vc.SCSpot << '\t' << vc.DRSpot << '\n';
    }
    else std::cerr << "\n\nEror: cannot open source file '" << fileName << "'\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

But, it is considere good practice to first read a complete line, then split it up in parts and then convert it to your structure elements.

Additionally: In C++ we often use an object oriented approach. Meaning, and objects methods, operating with the data are encapsulated in a class/struct.

In your case, we would overwrite the extractor `>>` and inserter operator `<<`.

This would then look like that (I am using C++17):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>

struct VacancyData {
    int CCSpot;
    int SNSpot;
    int TPSpot;
    int SCSpot;
    int DRSpot;
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, VacancyData& vc) {
        char c{};
        return is >> vc.CCSpot >> c >> vc.SNSpot >> c >> vc.TPSpot >> c >> vc.SCSpot >> c >> vc.DRSpot;
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const VacancyData& vc) {
        return os << vc.CCSpot << '\t' << vc.SNSpot << '\t' << vc.TPSpot << '\t' << vc.SCSpot << '\t' << vc.DRSpot;
    }
};

int main() {
    // Filename
    const std::string fileName{ "r:\\vacancy.txt" };

    // Open file and check, if it could be opened. Use C++17 if-statement with initializer
    if (std::ifstream vacancyFileStream{ fileName }; vacancyFileStream) {

        // Here we will store our data. Read complete file and parse it
        std::vector all(std::istream_iterator< VacancyData>(vacancyFileStream), {});

        // Ws there an error and could all data be read?
        if (vacancyFileStream.fail() || not vacancyFileStream.eof())
            std::cerr << "\n\nErorw hile reading input data\n\n";

        // Show output
        for (const VacancyData& vc : all)
            std::cout << vc << '\n';
    }
    else std::cerr << "\n\nEror: cannot open source file '" << fileName << "'\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Now, if you want to change the reading of your data, you can use any method that you want. For example, you can read a complete line, using `std::getline` use any method shown below to split the input string into parts. Then you can use any method to convert that string parts into an integer for your struct. You will just change the body of your extractor operator. Nothing else will be affected. That sis the beauty of encapsulation.

Regarding: Splitting a string into tokens is a very old task. There are many many solutions available. All have different properties. Some are difficult to understand, some are hard to develop, some are more complex, slower or faster or more flexible or not.

Alternatives

1. Handcrafted, many variants, using pointers or iterators,  maybe hard to develop and error prone.
2. Using old style `std::strtok` function. Maybe unsafe. Maybe should not be used any longer
3. `std::getline`. Most used implementation. But actually a "misuse" and not so flexible
4. Using dedicated modern function, specifically developed for this purpose, most flexible and good fitting into the STL environment and algortithm landscape. But slower.

Please see 4 examples in one piece of code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstring>
#include <forward_list>
#include <deque>

using Container = std::vector<std::string>;
std::regex delimiter{ "," };


int main() {

    // Some function to print the contents of an STL container
    auto print = [](const auto& container) -> void { std::copy(container.begin(), container.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<std::decay<decltype(*container.begin())>::type>(std::cout, " ")); std::cout << '\n'; };

    // Example 1:   Handcrafted -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    {
        // Our string that we want to split
        std::string stringToSplit{ "aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd" };
        Container c{};

        // Search for comma, then take the part and add to the result
        for (size_t i{ 0U }, startpos{ 0U }; i <= stringToSplit.size(); ++i) {

            // So, if there is a comma or the end of the string
            if ((stringToSplit[i] == ',') || (i == (stringToSplit.size()))) {

                // Copy substring
                c.push_back(stringToSplit.substr(startpos, i - startpos));
                startpos = i + 1;
            }
        }
        print(c);
    }

    // Example 2:   Using very old strtok function ----------------------------------------------------------
    {
        // Our string that we want to split
        std::string stringToSplit{ "aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd" };
        Container c{};

        // Split string into parts in a simple for loop
#pragma warning(suppress : 4996)
        for (char* token = std::strtok(const_cast<char*>(stringToSplit.data()), ","); token != nullptr; token = std::strtok(nullptr, ",")) {
            c.push_back(token);
        }

        print(c);
    }

    // Example 3:   Very often used std::getline with additional istringstream ------------------------------------------------
    {
        // Our string that we want to split
        std::string stringToSplit{ "aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd" };
        Container c{};

        // Put string in an std::istringstream
        std::istringstream iss{ stringToSplit };

        // Extract string parts in simple for loop
        for (std::string part{}; std::getline(iss, part, ','); c.push_back(part))
            ;

        print(c);
    }

    // Example 4:   Most flexible iterator solution  ------------------------------------------------

    {
        // Our string that we want to split
        std::string stringToSplit{ "aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd" };


        Container c(std::sregex_token_iterator(stringToSplit.begin(), stringToSplit.end(), delimiter, -1), {});
        //
        // Everything done already with range constructor. No additional code needed.
        //

        print(c);


        // Works also with other containers in the same way
        std::forward_list<std::string> c2(std::sregex_token_iterator(stringToSplit.begin(), stringToSplit.end(), delimiter, -1), {});

        print(c2);

        // And works with algorithms
        std::deque<std::string> c3{};
        std::copy(std::sregex_token_iterator(stringToSplit.begin(), stringToSplit.end(), delimiter, -1), {}, std::back_inserter(c3));

        print(c3);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

In modern C++ you would probably do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <regex>

// Regex for integer
const std::regex re{R"(([-+]?\d+))"};

struct VacancyData {
    int CCSpot;
    int SNSpot;
    int TPSpot;
    int SCSpot;
    int DRSpot;
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, VacancyData& vc) {
        // Read a  complete line and check, if that worked
        if (std::string line{}; std::getline(is, line)) {

            // Split the string into parts. The parts will definitely contain a integer
            std::vector part(std::sregex_token_iterator(line.begin(), line.end(), re), {});
            // Sanity check. Could we read 5 values?
            if (not (part.size() == 5u)) {
                std::cerr << "\n\nError while parsing line '" << line << '\n';
                is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
            }
            else {
                // Splitting the string worked. We will have intergers in the parts. stoi will not fail
                vc.CCSpot = std::stoi(part[0]);
                vc.SNSpot = std::stoi(part[1]);
                vc.TPSpot = std::stoi(part[2]);
                vc.SCSpot = std::stoi(part[3]);
                vc.DRSpot = std::stoi(part[4]);
            }
        }
        return is;
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const VacancyData& vc) {
        return os << vc.CCSpot << '\t' << vc.SNSpot << '\t' << vc.TPSpot << '\t' << vc.SCSpot << '\t' << vc.DRSpot;
    }
};

int main() {
    // Filename
    const std::string fileName{ "r:\\vacancy.txt" };

    // Open file and check, if it could be opened. Use C++17 if-statement with initializer
    if (std::ifstream vacancyFileStream{ fileName }; vacancyFileStream) {

        // Here we will store our data. Read complete file and parse it
        std::vector all(std::istream_iterator< VacancyData>(vacancyFileStream), {});

        // Show output
        for (const VacancyData& vc : all)
            std::cout << vc << '\n';
    }
    else std::cerr << "\n\nEror: cannot open source file '" << fileName << "'\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

But, there are tons of different possible solutions. And everybody can select whatever.

All above needs to be compiles with C++17.